# How to randomly split a generator into two generators by given ratio?

Tags: python, generator

Suppose one has a generator which yields some amount of data. 
Is there a way to obtain TWO generators which yield the same data where the amount of items those two generators yield is given by some ratio, e.g. generator 1 yields 80% of the data while generator 2 yields 20%. This should happen in a random way.

Of course producing a list of the first generator, shuffle and split the list into two parts is a straight forward solution. However I wonder if it is possible to achieve this without having to store the whole thing into memory.

Best,
Matt

Something I came up with is

```
def split_generator(data_generator, percentage_gen_1):
    original_generator, generator_copy = tee(data_generator)
    n_entries = sum(1 for item in generator_copy)

    split_idx = int(n_entries * percentage_gen_1)

    gen_1 = islice(original_generator, 0, split_idx)

    # I found that the remaining part of original_generator works
    # as the remaining (1 - percentage_gen_1) part

    return gen_1, original_generator
```

There are two drawbacks to this. It is not random and I think tee stores the whole thing into memory so there is no reason to do this over conversion to a list.

Comment: To split something a given percentage, you need to know how long it is. Finding the length of a generator requires iterating over the whole thing which in general can't be done twice, which mean you would need to store the values generated. So, no, you can't do this and avoid storing the whole thing in memory.

Comment: Your comment says "I found that the remaining part of original_generator works as the remaining (1 - percentage_gen_1) part", but that's not true. It only seems to work if you exhaust the first generator first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution doesn't store values.  It sets up two identical generators and two identical random number streams.  The generators share the same cutoff percentage and one only yields below it and the other only yields above it:

```
from random import Random

def percentage_generators(generator, percentage):

    def generator_1(state):
        twister = Random()
        twister.setstate(state)

        for value in generator():
            if twister.random() < percentage:
                yield value

    def generator_2(state):
        twister = Random()
        twister.setstate(state)

        for value in generator():
            if twister.random() >= percentage:
                yield value

    state = Random().getstate()

    return [generator_1(state), generator_2(state)]

if __name__ == "__main__":

    def test_generator():
        for n in range(20):
            yield n

    generator1, generator2 = percentage_generators(test_generator, 0.7)

    for number in generator1:
        print(1, number)

    print()

    for number in generator2:
        print(2, number)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
% python3 test.py
1 0
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 6
1 7
1 8
1 10
1 11
1 12
1 13
1 14
1 15
1 17

2 4
2 5
2 9
2 16
2 18
2 19
%
```

The code can probably be reduced by generating the generator wrappers via a loop, i.e. looping over `operator.lt` and `operator.ge`, or some such.

Comment: This does of course depend on being able to run the generator twice and get the same output with no side effects.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach which stores some of the generator's values in memory, but not all of them. In particular, it only stores the values in between the ones that were last yielded by either generator. For example, when generating positive integers, if `a` last yielded 23, and `b` last yielded 42, then only 24 through 41 will be stored in memory.

```
from collections import deque
import random

def randsplit(g):
    g = iter(g)
    queues = [deque(), deque()]

    def fill_queues():
        x = next(g)
        if random.random() < 0.8:
            queues[0].append(x)
        else:
            queues[1].append(x)

    def iter_from_queue(q):
        while True:
            while not q:
                try:
                    fill_queues()
                except StopIteration:
                    return
            yield q.popleft()

    return [iter_from_queue(queues[0]), iter_from_queue(queues[1])]

a,b = randsplit(range(20))

print("iterating through a.")
for item in a: print(item)

print("iterating through b.")
for item in b: print(item)
```

One possible result:

```
iterating through a.
0
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
iterating through b.
1
2
10
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks for this great answer! Works with any data structure as well. Worth mentioning that one generator might end up being empty. Also it might be a good idea to keep the percentage as a parameter of the method. Best

Comment: You're still going to end up storing the whole content of one generator if you exhaust the other first, as you do in this example. It's very hard to use this efficiently, because there's no indication of how much data is being cached for which generator, so barring nasty closure inspection, there's no way to know which generator you "should" be advancing to iterate efficiently.